# ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes - Error after scipy.io import

Tags: python, scipy, pip, pytest

After updating scipy, numpy and pandas to the newest versions, I receive the following error whenever I attempt to run my code on a Windows 10 machine with Python 3.7.4:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "Path\To\MyClass.py", line 3, in <module>
    import scipy.io as sio
  File "Path\To\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 68, in <module>
    from ._lib.deprecation import _deprecated
  File "Path\To\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._testutils import PytestTester
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

This is how the last file looks like:

```
"""
Module containing private utility functions
===========================================

The ``scipy._lib`` namespace is empty (for now). Tests for all
utilities in submodules of ``_lib`` can be run with::

    from scipy import _lib
    _lib.test()

"""
from scipy._lib._testutils import PytestTester
test = PytestTester(__name__)
del PytestTester
```

Am I running into a bug or is my setup broken?

Comment: This runs fine for me in Conda. The error looks like there is something wrong with your scipy?

Comment: I am not getting this error with scipy `1.6.0` and python `3.8.5`. I also can't get the error with python `3.9` .

Comment: Probably there is a problem with my scipy package. I can't even uninstall it. "pip uninstall scipy" just leads to an "_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte" error.

Comment: @Hagbard You can always delete it manually.

Comment: I managed to reinstall scipy now but unfortunately the Problem still persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by reinstalling Anaconda. I still don't know the source of the problem though.